# What does double forward slash asterisk "//*" do in React router route path matching?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

Our code base has the following lines:

```
<Routes basename={basePath}>
  <Route path={loginPath} element={<LoginPage />}></Route>
  <Route path={forgotPswdPath} element={<ForgotPassword />}></Route>
  <Route path={resetPswdPath} element={<ResetPassword />}></Route>
  <Route path="//*" element={<MainApp />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

in which `<MainApp/>` goes on to return more `<Route/>` in `<Routes/>`.

What does the `//*` matching the `<MainApp/>` do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//* will catch the double slash in url, path is converted to regex using path-to-regexp .

Regex for //* is /^//((?:.*))(?:/(?=$))?$/i .

You may test it in any online regex tool to find the different matches